# Nothing could get any better than firsthand experience (correct phrase)

Tags: phrases

Let's say nothing could beat firsthand experience. And you say:

> Nothing **could get any better** than firsthand experience.

Or

> Nothing **can be better** than firsthand experience.

Which is correct to express what I am really trying to say?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In normal conversation, this can be said in many ways, e.g.:

> Nothing beats first-hand experience.
>
> There is nothing better than first-hand experience.
>
> Nothing can take the place of first-hand experience.

The two examples that you provide are acceptable, although I personally would not express your intended message in those words. The phrases 'could be better' and 'can be better' imply the **possibility** (perhaps even the probability) that one thing can/could be better than another. However, I interpret your intended meaning to be that 'first-hand experience' is **always** better than any other type of experience. If my interpretation is correct, then it might be better to replace 'could be better/can be better' with 'is better'. The use of 'is better' does not simply imply the possibility of a better outcome; it states it as an absolute certainty.

Comment: As for my examples, are they both correct or something?